# column doesnt match when its empty

Tags: php, mysql

How should i solve this? there is not a row 1 and i cant insert or update data. Unique keys are indeed ip and uid in my table.

My code is as follows:

```
//Retrive listeners per reload
echo 'Data H&ouml;gan&auml;s <br>';
$sc="http://USER:PWD@SUB.SERVER.se:10000/admin.cgi?sid=1&mode=viewxml&page=3";
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file($sc);
foreach ($xml2->LISTENERS->LISTENER as $listener2) {

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = " insert INTO hoganaskey
        (ip, uid, tid, starttid, date)
    VALUES
        ('$listener2->HOSTNAME', '$listener2->UID', '$listener2->CONNECTTIME', '$listener2->USERAGENT', '$starttid', '$date')
    on duplicate key
        update tid='$listener2->CONNECTTIME' ";

//$sql = "INSERT INTO hoganaskey (ip, uid, tid, ua, starttid, date) VALUES('$listener2->HOSTNAME', '$listener2->UID', '$listener2->CONNECTTIME', '$listener2->USERAGENT' '$starttid', '$date') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tid='$listener2->CONNECTTIME' ";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

} //End foreach SHOUcast listener
```

Im returning this error in insert "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

Comment: I saw there is "ua" in your commented query. But it is missing in the uncommented query.

Answer (score 1):

In your insert query, you listed only 5 field names:

```
(ip, uid, tid, starttid, date)
```

but you are passing 6 values not 5:

```
('$listener2->HOSTNAME', '$listener2->UID', '$listener2->CONNECTTIME', '$listener2->USERAGENT', '$starttid', '$date')
```